# Having Trouble with creating user accounts in Linux with Python script

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

```
def createUser(username,password):
    password = crypt.crypt(password,"$5$a1")
    os.system("sudo useradd -p '#{password}' -m "+username)

    createUser("lesson1",idhash)
```

This is the code I have for creating user accounts so far, but each time the user account is created the password that is inserted in the method definition is not the password for the newly created account.

Comment: You're not using the password variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the following line to use username and password:

```
os.system("sudo useradd -p {} -m {}".format(password, username))
```

Comment: Try cleartext password first, if it works then there is an issue with your idhash variable

Comment: i also changed the password to plain text and am still receiving the "invalid password" error

Comment: You are getting the error when creating the user or when trying to login?

Comment: when trying to login

Comment: That is normal, because when creating users with `useradd`, you need to provide an encrypted password. Now check the value of idhash

Comment: i thought thats what the crypt command was for in the above code?

Comment: Yeah, I thought you removed that when you tried cleartext password. If you are still using `crypt.crypt()` then the only error can be in `idhash`, where is it coming from?

Comment: idhash is just a string declared early on in the script

Comment: check the value of it, make sure you are using the same password stored in there

Comment: yeah everything is the same. but the crypt.crypt() command changes the password. Would that affect the original string?

Comment: No, changing `password` variable inside the function doesn't change `idhash`. Is your indentation correct? because in your post it isn't

Comment: yes the indentation is correct, I fixed the problem. I just had to change the salt. Thanks for helping me through this.